# How to add tooltip in easy way?

Tags: javascript, tooltip

Just Take Class Name or ID name form console.

```
$('#tablel_id').attr('data-toggle','tooltip');
$('#table_id').attr('title','Add Your massage');
```

or

```
$('.class_name').attr('data-toggle','tooltip');
$('.class_name').attr('title','Add Your massage');
```

and you can also use.

```
$('#table_ID').title="Add Your Massage";
$('.table_class_name').title="Add Your Massage";
```

Comment: you are posting the same thing as your answer post, if you are trying to ask a question and answer it by yourself, this is not how you do it. You need to post your question first explaining the question in detail, not only putting it in the title. And then you can post the answer as an answer post

Answer (score 0):

Just Take Class Name or ID name form console.

```
$('#tablel_id').attr('data-toggle','tooltip'); 
$('#table_id').attr('title','Add Your massage');
```

or

```
$('.class_name').attr('data-toggle','tooltip'); 
$('.class_name').attr('title','Add Your massage');
```

and you can also use.

```
$('#table_ID').title="Add Your Massage"; 
$('.table_class_name').title="Add Your Massage";
```

Comment: You should format both your question and answer properly.